# will there be an integration of Nemo or Marlin as Ubuntu standard filemanager?

Tags: nemo, marlin

as the Gnome developers decided to make Nautilus unusable and unuseful, are there plans to integrate a new file manager or a fork into Ubuntu as the standard filemanager?
i would love to see Marlin to be perfectly integrated because it has "miller-columns" and many other useful functions as well as all the functions that are actually missing in Nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

From [OMGUbuntu.co.uk](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/ubuntus-default-file-manager-debated-at-uds):

> Discussion on Ubuntu 13.04′s choice of default file manager was one of the headline sessions in the second day of the latest UDS.
>
> Integration, design and accessibility issues were all raised during the 50 minute discussion, which centered around what Ubuntu needs to patch or re-add to the ‘new’ Nautilus for it to remain useful to Ubuntu users.
>
> ...
>
> Overall the mood throughout the discussion was upbeat and constructive. The attendees recognise that Nautilus is still the best all-round file manager available for Ubuntu and as such it makes sense to use it.
>
> The coming months will see definitie decisions taken on the issues raised.
>
> But for now we can feel assured that the loss of shortcuts, functionality, accessibility, and Ubuntu integration are being taken seriously.

---

So no, Nautilus is there to stay for a while. Of course it is up for review every UDS ;)

Comment: but i would like to know if i am the only user who is really annoyed by the way the Gnome developers go with Nautilus and "global-menues" Completely removing functions can't be the way! Making it "easier" for newbies is good but that could be achieved by simply changing the default options and let advanced users activate their preferred funtionality! removing of useful functions is a step back in my opinion!

Comment: Hmmm I have no beef with nautilus but I am more command line anyways but from the gist of the coverage of UDS I would say that those that are envolved still are on Nautilus side. BUT! nobody is stopping you from using another file manager ;)